# Method said isn't defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I keep getting this error, but it clearly says the method is defined.

```
undefined method `customer_ID' for Order(id: string, order_date: string, customer_ID:      string):Class
Extracted source (around line #23):

20:     @orderlines= Orderline.find(:all)
21:    
22:         # copy each field into a variable for display
23:          @id= Order.customer_ID
24:     # @date= Order.order_date
25:     %>
26:     <h1>Showing all orders</h1>
RAILS_ROOT: /mounts/u-zon-d2/ugrad/jdpa227/rails1
```

Comment: customer_ID is notdefined at the class level but at the instance level.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a customer_ID attribute on you active record model but you are missing a getter to access the instance variable from outside the class.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_reader :customer_ID
end
```

of

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  def customer_ID
    self[:customer_ID]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any attributes or methods that is named as `customer_ID`?

In ruby, alphabet case matters, so if you have a method or attribute named `customer_id`, it won't be found if you look for `customer_ID`.

By convention, method and attribute names are all lower case separated by `_`.

So try `customer_id`.